# Objecto se extiende de manera infinita al declarar un objeto como una variable en vez de usar la expresión del mismo

Tags: javascript, javascript-objeto

Tengo un arreglo de datos que consiste en objetos (transacciones) con un timestamp dentro de ellos bajo el nombre de `start`, necesito crear un objeto a partir de estos datos que me ayuden a visualizar en periodos de tiempo (año, mes, día) cuántas transacciones fueron echas para cada uno de estos periodos( En el código original hay muchos más datos para cada transacción y necesito procesar información más que compleja que simplemente contar cuántas son, sin embargo, reduje el código para ahorrarles tiempo y demostrar el problema de una manera más concisa). Este es el array que contiene los datos:

```
const data =[
  {
    "start": "2020-09-07T22:27:24.000Z"
  },
  {
    "start": "2020-09-08T12:27:24.000Z"
  },
  {
    "start": "2020-09-08T22:27:24.000Z"
  },
  {
    "start": "2020-11-08T22:27:24.000Z"
  },
  {
    "start": "2019-11-08T22:27:24.000Z"
  }
]
```

Cada objecto representa una transacción. Lo que necesitaba era crear un objeto que me diga cuántas transacciones se hicieron cada año, cada mes y cada día. Esta fue mi primera solución:

```
const getAllData = (transactions) =>{
    //Arreglo vació para guardar todos los datos
    let processedTransactions ={};
    //Iterar cada transacción
    transactions.forEach( ({start}) =>{
        //Obtengo el día, mes y año
        const startDate = new Date(start);
        const day = startDate.getDate();
        const month = startDate.getMonth();
        const year = startDate.getFullYear();
        const yearDiff = new Date().getFullYear() - year;
        //Valido el timestamp es valido y si la transacción fue efectuada en los últimos 3 años.
        if( !Number.isNaN(day)  && !Number.isNaN(month) && !Number.isNaN(year) && yearDiff<3){
            //Reviso si el año existe y si no es así creo un objeto dentro de el
            processedTransactions[year] = processedTransactions[year] || {count : 0};
            //Acumulo cuentas para el año
            processedTransactions[year].count++;

            //Reviso si el mes existe y si no es así creo un objeto dentro de el
            processedTransactions[year][month] = processedTransactions[year][month] || {count : 0};
            //Acumulo cuentas para el mes
            processedTransactions[year][month].count++;

            //Reviso si el día existe y si no es así creo un objeto dentro de el
            processedTransactions[year][month][day] = processedTransactions[year][month][day] || {count : 0};
            //Acumulo cuentas para el día
            processedTransactions[year][month][day].count++; 

        }  
    });
    return processedTransactions;
}
```

Funciona bien, la función devuelve este objeto:

```
{
   "2019":{
      "10":{
         "8":{
            "count":1
         },
         "count":1
      },
      "count":1
   },
   "2020":{
      "8":{
         "7":{
            "count":1
         },
         "8":{
            "count":2
         },
         "count":3
      },
      "10":{
         "8":{
            "count":1
         },
         "count":1
      },
      "count":4
   }
}
```

De esta manera puedo saber cuantas transacciones fueron realizadas en el 2019 utilizando `processedTransactions.2019.count` o cuántas fueron hechas el 8 de Setiembre del 2020 con  `processedTransactions.2020.8.8.count` y así luego puedo graficar los datos.

Luego decidí hacer el código más fácil de leer y declaré este objeto:

```
const defaultData = {count : 0};
```

Así puedo cambiar estas líneas de código:

```
processedTransactions[year] = processedTransactions[year] || {count : 0};
...
processedTransactions[year][month] = processedTransactions[year][month] || {count : 0};
...
processedTransactions[year][month][day] = processedTransactions[year][month][day] || {count : 0};
```

Por estas:

```
processedTransactions[year] = processedTransactions[year] || defaultData;
...
processedTransactions[year][month] = processedTransactions[year][month] || defaultData;
...
processedTransactions[year][month][day] = processedTransactions[year][month][day] || defaultData;
```

Entonces la función terminó así:

```
const getAllDataII = (transactions) =>{
    //Arreglo vació para guardar todos los datos
    let processedTransactions ={};
    const defaultData = {count : 0};
    //Iterar cada transacción
    transactions.forEach( ({start}) =>{
        //Obtengo el día, mes y año
        const startDate = new Date(start);
        const day = startDate.getDate();
        const month = startDate.getMonth();
        const year = startDate.getFullYear();
        const yearDiff = new Date().getFullYear() - year;
        //Valido el timestamp es valido y si la transacción fue efectuada en los últimos 3 años.
        if( !Number.isNaN(day)  && !Number.isNaN(month) && !Number.isNaN(year) && yearDiff<3){
            //Reviso si el año existe y si no es así creo un objeto dentro de el
            processedTransactions[year] = processedTransactions[year] || defaultData;
            //Acumulo cuentas para el año
            processedTransactions[year].count++;

            //Reviso si el mes existe y si no es así creo un objeto dentro de el
            processedTransactions[year][month] = processedTransactions[year][month] || defaultData;
            //Acumulo cuentas para el mes
            processedTransactions[year][month].count++;

            //Reviso si el día existe y si no es así creo un objeto dentro de el
            processedTransactions[year][month][day] = processedTransactions[year][month][day] || defaultData;
            //Acumulo cuentas para el día
            processedTransactions[year][month][day].count++; 

        }  
    });
    return processedTransactions;
}
```

Pero ahora no funciona, el objeto que la función devuelve se hace infinito, así:

```
{
  '2019': {
    '7': {
      '7':{
        '7':{
          '7':{
             '7':{
                  ...
```

¿Qué está pasando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el primer caso, `{count : 0}` es un objeto nuevo cada ocasión:

```
processedTransactions[year] = processedTransactions[year] || {count : 0};
    ...
processedTransactions[year][month] = processedTransactions[year][month] || {count : 0};
```

En el segundo caso siempre se está usando el mismo objeto, eso puede estar generando el error

```
processedTransactions[year] = processedTransactions[year] || defaultData;
...
processedTransactions[year][month] = processedTransactions[year][month] || defaultData;
```

Ejemplo:

```js
function getObjeto(){
  return {count : 0};
}

// objetos únicos
let o1 = getObjeto();
let o2 = getObjeto();

o1.count = 1;
o2.count = 2;

console.log(o1);
console.log(o2);


// objeto compartido
const objeto = { count : 0};

let o3 = objeto;
let o4 = objeto;

o3.count = 3;
o4.count = 4;

// ambas variables tienen el mismo objeto
console.log(o3);
console.log(o4);
```

Comment: Pareces estar en lo correcto, la solución con la función resuelve el problema. Muchas gracias